# Applying MakeUppercase to non-English characters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have some macros to distinguish between two varieties of similar objects.  So, for example, I need `\psi` to come out as expected, but `\MakeUppercase{\psi}` to come out as `\Psi`.  (Obviously my real applications are more complicated than this.)  Is this possible to do in any reasonable way?

At the moment, the non-English characters I need are limited to greek, and `\eth` and `\thorn` if possible.  But I'm writing these papers to be posted to the arXiv, and as I understand it xelatex and lualatex just don't work on arXiv -- even pdflatex is hard enough to wrangle in my experience.  So I'm basically restricted to plain old (pdf)latex.

---

**EDIT**

For reference, here's what I ended up using.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareSymbolFont{wasy}{U}{wasy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thorn}{\mathord}{wasy}{105}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Thorn}{\mathord}{wasy}{106}

\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\@uclclist{%
    \eth\Eth
    \thorn\Thorn
    \alpha\Alpha
    \beta\Beta
    \gamma\Gamma
    \delta\Delta
    \epsilon\Epsilon
    \varepsilon\Varepsilon
    \zeta\Zeta
    \eta\Eta
    \theta\Theta
    \vartheta\Vartheta
    \iota\Iota
    \kappa\Kappa
    \lambda\Lambda
    \mu\Mu
    \nu\Nu
    \xi\Xi
    \omicron\Omicron
    \pi\Pi
    \varpi\Varpi
    \rho\Rho
    \varrho\Varrho
    \sigma\Sigma
    \varsigma\Varsigma
    \tau\Tau
    \upsilon\Upsilon
    \phi\Phi
    \varphi\Varphi
    \chi\Chi
    \psi\Psi
    \omega\Omega
  }
  \newcommand\Eth{\text{\DH}}
  \newcommand\Alpha{\mathrm{A}}
  \newcommand\Beta{\mathrm{B}}
  \newcommand\Epsilon{\mathrm{E}}
  \newcommand\Varepsilon{\mathit{E}}
  \newcommand\Zeta{\mathrm{Z}}
  \newcommand\Eta{\mathrm{H}}
  \newcommand\Vartheta{\varTheta}
  \newcommand\Iota{\mathrm{I}}
  \newcommand\Kappa{\mathrm{K}}
  \newcommand\Mu{\mathrm{M}}
  \newcommand\Nu{\mathrm{N}}
  \newcommand\omicron{o}
  \newcommand\Omicron{\mathrm{O}}
  \newcommand{\Varpi}{\varPi}
  \newcommand\Rho{\mathrm{P}}
  \newcommand\Varrho{\mathit{P}}
  \newcommand\Varsigma{\varSigma}
  \newcommand\Varphi{\varPhi}
  \newcommand\Tau{\mathrm{T}}
  \newcommand\Chi{\mathrm{X}}
\makeatother
```

[image: Result of iterating through the above code]

---

**EDIT 2**

I also experimented with combining the two answers with something like the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myMakeUppercase[1]{%%
  \begingroup
  \let\new@uclclist\@uclclist
  \g@addto@macro\new@uclclist{%
    \eth\Eth
    ...
    \omega\Omega
  }
  \let\@uclclist\new@uclclist%
  \MakeUppercase{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

This allows me to just do the upcasing inside my command, and keep the standard casing everywhere else.  I'm not totally sure why I had to make a temporary copy of the list.  (I guess `\g@addto@macro` actually changes the data in place???)  But it seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a curious requirement: usually the problem is how *not* to make math uppercase, because symbols are not linked to their uppercase variant.

However, you need to update the `\@uclclist` variable that contains the pairs of letters for uppercasing/lowercasing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@uclclist{\psi\Psi\omega\Omega\alpha\Alpha}
\newcommand\Alpha{\mathrm{A}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello

$\MakeUppercase{Hello World \alpha\omega\psi}:\alpha\omega\psi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's easier to use, alright.  Thank you!

Comment: @Mike Supplement it with the characters you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility that I've modeled somewhat on how `\MakeUppercase` is defined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\myMakeUppercase[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \let\psi\Psi
    \let\omega\Omega
    \def\alpha{A}%%
    \MakeUppercase{#1}%%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

Hello

$\myMakeUppercase{Hello World \alpha\omega\psi}:\alpha\omega\psi$

\end{document}
```

I am assuming that the characters you want to uppercase are already control sequences.  For each such control sequence for which you want an uppercase version, you add a line which is either

```
\let<cs name><cs name>
```

or

```
\def<cs name>{<replacement string>}
```

[image]

Comment: Not as elegant as I had hoped, but it'll do the job.  :)  Thanks!