# Greek letter case matching in memoir class

Tags: macros, greek

I've written some documents using a macro file to make writing math easier. In some of these macros, I use the answer from [Applying MakeUppercase to non-English characters in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248612/applying-makeuppercase-to-non-english-characters-in-math-mode) to use \MakeUppercase and \MakeLowercase on greek letters.

The problem occurs now that I'm trying to collect these documents together in a thesis. I've narrowed it down to having something to do with the document class being memoir (or rather, the thesis class uses `\LoadClassWithOptions{memoir}`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xargs}
    
%%%Greek letter case matching%%%
\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\@uclclist{%
    \delta\Delta
    \tau\Tau
  }
\newcommand\Tau{\mathrm{T}}

%Math macros%
\newcommandx\setnamestyle[1]
{
    \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax % use mathcal unless control sequence (greek letter)
        \MakeUppercase{#1} %greek letter or multiple chars
    \else
        \mathcal{\MakeUppercase{#1}} % single char
    \fi
}
        
\newcommandx\set[2]
{
    % set (uppercase)
    \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname#1set\endcsname{\ensuremath{
        \setnamestyle{#2}
     }}
     % element of set (lowercase)
    \expandafter\newcommandx\csname#1\endcsname{\ensuremath{
        \MakeLowercase{#2}
    }}  
    % element in set
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1inset\endcsname{\ensuremath{
            \csname#1\endcsname \in \csname#1set\endcsname
    }}
    % sum of elements in set
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1sum\endcsname{\ensuremath{
            \sum_{\csname#1inset\endcsname}
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\set{testSetA}{A}
\testSetA\qquad\testSetAinset\qquad\testSetAsum

\set{testSetTau}{\Tau}
\testSetTau\qquad\testSetTauinset\qquad\testSetTausum

\set{testSetDelta}{\delta}
\testSetDelta\qquad\testSetDeltainset\qquad\testSetDeltasum
\end{document}
```

Using the article document class yields the expected result of:

[image]

Whereas when using the memoir class, the greek letters are not correctly manipulated:

[image]

Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether typing `\SetDeltasum` is better than `\sum_{\delta\in\Delta}`.

Comment: Note that `memoir` uses `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}` and thus replaces `\MakeUppercase` by `\MakeTextUppercase`, and that seems to be the problem. You get the same result if you add `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}` to your `article` example.

Comment: Additionally I kind of agree with egreg, this kind of syntax might end up biting you in the long run.

Comment: I had no idea `memoir` replaced `\MakeUppercase`, thanks @daleif.

Comment: Also, I agree using \set{testSetDelta}{\delta} is silly. These macros have proven to be useful for abstraction and made it much easier to change the representation of sets and their elements. This is an MWE and the full setup is much more involved and can handle special cases (like @egreg points out in his answer), uniform presentation of constraints, and more.

Comment: We did that quite a while ago especially because of math in the headers (`memoirs` default headers are in upper case, tough I normally always disable this in all my documents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to re-write your document to use Unicode and expl3, which give you some better primitives for this.  (**ETA:** I see that @egreg went ahead and wrote that.)  However, the minimal fix to make this work in PDFTeX is:

- Include `alphabeta` so that `\alpha`, `\Tau`, etc. are defined in text mode and `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` work on them
- Include `amsmath` or `amstext` to be able to insert text-mode commands as math symbols
- Render your Greek letters in text-mode, wrapped in `\textnormal`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xargs}

%Math macros%
\newcommandx\setnamestyle[1]
{
    \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax % use mathcal unless control sequence (greek letter)
        \mathord{\textnormal{\MakeUppercase{#1}}} %greek letter or multiple chars
    \else
        \mathcal{\MakeUppercase{#1}} % single char
    \fi
}
        
\newcommandx\set[2]
{
    % set (uppercase)
    \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname#1set\endcsname{\ensuremath{
        \setnamestyle{#2}
     }}
     % element of set (lowercase)
    \expandafter\newcommandx\csname#1\endcsname{\ensuremath{
        \mathord{\textnormal{\itshape\MakeLowercase{#2}}}
    }}  
    % element in set
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1inset\endcsname{\ensuremath{
            \csname#1\endcsname \in \csname#1set\endcsname
    }}
    % sum of elements in set
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1sum\endcsname{\ensuremath{
            \sum_{\csname#1inset\endcsname}
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\set{testSetA}{A}
\testSetA\qquad\testSetAinset\qquad\testSetAsum

\set{testSetTau}{\Tau}
\testSetTau\qquad\testSetTauinset\qquad\testSetTausum

\set{testSetDelta}{\delta}
\testSetDelta\qquad\testSetDeltainset\qquad\testSetDeltasum
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

Listing the fonts in the document would show that this is technically using a LGR-encoded text font rather than your OML or OT1-encoded math font, but for the default font family, most of the glyphs are the same. You might run into problems with some letters, such as `\lambda`, `\vartheta` and `\varphi`. If you need to fix this, seriously consider the expl3 approach instead.

If you wanted to be able to insert Greek UTF-8 characters into your source, it would be possible to make that work in expl3, but I left that part of the code unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, @Davislor. This fixes the problem without requiring many changes. Although expl3 does look interesting. I'll look into that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `memoir` uses `\MakeUppercase` as modified by the `textcase` package, which is meant to *ignore* uppercasing for math.

You can get the same result with a different approach, not relying on `\MakeUppercase` or `\MakeLowercase`.

To be honest, I don't think you gain much by typing something like `\SetAsum` instead of `\sum_{a\in A}` and you lose in flexibility, because you can't do `\sum_{a'\in A}`, for instance.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{memoir}
    
\providecommand\Tau{\mathrm{T}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%Math macros
\cs_new_protected:Nn \rasmus_set_namestyle:n
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1 { #1 } { \mathcal{#1} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1set }
   {
    \rasmus_set_namestyle:n { #2 }
   }
  % element of set (lowercase)
  \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1 }
   {
    \token_if_cs:NTF { #2 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { \str_lowercase:f { \cs_to_str:N #2 } }
     }
     {
      \str_lowercase:n { #2 }
     }
   }
  % element in set
  \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1inset }
   {
    \exp_not:c { #1 } \exp_not:N \in \exp_not:c { #1set }
   }
  % sum of elements in set
  \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1sum }
   {
    \exp_not:n { \sum\sb } { \exp_not:c { #1inset } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\set{testSetA}{A}
$\testSetA\qquad\testSetAinset\qquad\testSetAsum$

\set{testSetTau}{\Tau}
$\testSetTau\qquad\testSetTauinset\qquad\testSetTausum$

\set{testSetDelta}{\delta}
$\testSetDelta\qquad\testSetDeltainset\qquad\testSetDeltasum$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed all `\ensuremath` parts that just add to the complication. Being able to type `\SetDelta` in text mode is not much more economic than `$\SetDelta$` which instead carries semantics.

Note: if I ask LaTeX to show the definition of the commands with

```
\texttt{\meaning\testSetDelta}

\texttt{\meaning\testSetDeltainset}

\texttt{\meaning\testSetDeltasum}
```

I get

[image]

so no `\csname` in the replacement texts.